# Make an image responsive by height AND width

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site for a client, using a purchased Wordpress theme (so all the code is not necessarily mine, but I can pull something if needed).

The landing page has a responsive background image. On top of that, I need to use images to show the relevant logos (the fields where I input this were intended for text, but they allow images with no problem). The image has a border wrap around it also, and then people can scroll down from there to see the rest of the content.

My problem: on desktop, the logos will rescale with the WIDTH fine. But one of my clients is viewing in a very widescale-oriented browser window (which I figure is unusual across all users, but it's the client!), and the logos do not rescale with HEIGHT changes, so they get cut off by the border wrap.

I've tried things like

```
.home-section img {
max-height: 50%;
}
```

Which is what the theme's developer provided initially, and also changed 50% to 50vh (just trying some things I came across online, not a code expert by any means), and also a variation of this solution [HERE](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/responsive-centered-square-div-resizes-height/)
with no luck.

My (again, partial) understanding is that since the height of the div with the background image isn't set explicitly, I can't use a percentage height for the logo/child element, but is there a way to solve this?

I'm currently using srcset to get the logos the right size for mobile, but that's not a perfect solution. I figured there may be a javascript solution too, but I'm only about 75% with HTML & CSS and not much with JS/PHP without explicit directions. (Call it capable, but inexperienced).

You can view the issue [HERE](http://ssspectacular.zooatlanta.org).

Thank you!

=================================================

EDIT:
A coworker came across this solution, which improves things greatly. The issue still happens at a short enough browser (IE landscape phone viewing, etc), but works on a greater range of viewport sizes:

```
div.home-section-image {
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: calc(690px * (90/150));
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
}
```

The logos now scale vertically to a point, though the viewport height can still catch them and cut them off, but at a better threshold (at ~550px high, where it happened at ~720px high previously - now well beyond a normal person's minimum browser size, my understanding is ~760px is average).

I tried to combine this with @kburgie's code suggestions to keep the logos completely above the green border, but my results ended up pushing the logos off the TOP of the page instead, which is worse (for me, on a horizontal Galaxy S3, I can at least get the main square of the top logo to display, which is enough for me at that size).

Thanks to everyone who helped - I think this may be the best solution I can pull for now!

Comment: It's not clear which image you're referring to. The green/gray text image?

Comment: It's two images, but same problem - the "ALL NEW"/"Scaly Slimy Spectacular" green logo, and the #ONLYZOOATL graphic below it. (I guess they could be one graphic, but I'd have the same problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should be able to combine width and height media queries to catch that edge case:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-height: 500px) {
    .home-section img {
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that

Comment: I popped this into the Custom CSS field of the theme, and it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The issue is basically that because of that green border around the landing image, the logos get cut off when the window is too short, rather than just being below the fold and having people able to scroll down to see them. However, the client likes how that works outside of this one issue, so I can't just change that, unfortunately.

Any ideas? Or ideas why the suggested code wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment or I would. I think isherwood's media query is too specific.

Responsive images should already be responsive by height AND width, and the best way to handle that is by working with the image width.

This is a dangerous selector and you should get rid of it:

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

It will affect ALL images on your site. You should use a class instead. Beyond that, your images are already set to max-width: 100%, which is all you need.

Focus on your positioning instead

Step 1: Remove your margin top and bottom

```
.home-section .container { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Step 2: Absolutely position the image container at the bottom of it's parent. Then it will always stay above the green border. Stick it in a media query if you'd only like this positioning above a certain screen size.

```
.home-section-image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
 }
```